# Change onclick="showMore()" onmouseover

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

```
<input id="button" type="button" value="Expand" onclick="showMore()">

<div id="d3">
<div class="button12" onclick="document.location='#'">Home</div>
<div class="button12" onclick="document.location='#'">About</div>
<div id="d1">
    <input type="button" value="Shrink" onclick="showLess()">
</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 

var button = document.getElementById("button");
var d3 = document.getElementById("d3");
function showMore() {
    button.style.display="none";
    d3.style.display="block";
}

function showLess() {
    button.style.display="inline-block";
    d3.style.display="none";
}
//]]>  

</script>
```

How can I change `onclick="showMore()"` to `hover..`?

I need it to show without clicking it.

Comment: use some CSS code to make hover style

Comment: `onmouseover="showMore()"` didn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `onmouseover` instead of `onclick`

like this

```
<input id="button" type="button" value="Expand" onmouseover="showMore()">

<div id="d3">
<div class="button12" onclick="document.location='#'">Home</div>
<div class="button12" onclick="document.location='#'">About</div>
<div id="d1">
    <input type="button" value="Shrink" onclick="showLess()">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanx Satish Sharma for a quick solution.

Comment: Done.. But If i want to make this work in this <img type="button" src="xxxxx.jpg" height="52" width="72">

Comment: add this function to <img> tag like this `<img type="button" src="xxxxx.jpg" height="52" width="72" onmouseover="showMore()"> `

Comment: remember this is an event an works for every html tag as you see in `<input id="button"..` . check there is some function or not

Answer (score 0):

use css style like this

```
#btn2:hover
{
//your design here
}
```

or use `onmouseover` like this

```
<input id="button" type="button" id="btn2" value="Expand" onmouseover="showMore()">
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change to `onmouseover="showMore()"`

If you are not able to edit (not able to access ) the code ,you can try something like this on page load or any perticulat event .

```
$('#yourID').attr ('onClick', "onmousover");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#button").mouseover(function(){
    $("#button").hide();
});
```